# d3 linear scale not working in yAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a problem with yAxis scale. For some countries it works fine but for some it doesn't. Like you can see on the picture for example for the data for Russia it works fine, but for Brasil it doesn't. The data is from the world bank data.
[scale working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCPx.png)

[scale working wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxhVT.png)

Code:

```
var width = 960,
  height = 600;

var widthChart = 460,
  heightChart = 300;

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  left : 50,
  bottom : 30
}   

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([margin.left, widthChart - margin.right]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([heightChart - margin.top, margin.bottom]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(7)
  .orient("left");  

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
  .interpolate("basis");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(150)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 1.5]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").select(".container").select(".center-    block").select(".map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var svgLineChart = d3.select("body").select(".container").select(".lineChart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", widthChart)
  .attr("id", "svgLineChart")
  .attr("height", heightChart);

var color = d3.scale.linear().range(["#bfddfc","#1e4770"]);    

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
          .attr('class', 'hidden tooltip');    

queue()  
  .defer(d3.json, 'countries.topo.json')
  .defer(d3.csv, 'countriesModified.csv')
  .await(visualize);

function visualize(error, countries, data) {
if (error) return console.error(error);

var countriesObj = {};
var countriesArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    countriesObj[i] = {
        countryName : data[i].CountryName,
        countryCode : data[i].CountryCode, 
        years : [
            {year : "1961", value : data[i].y1961},
            {year : "1962", value : data[i].y1962},
            {year : "1963", value : data[i].y1963},
            {year : "1964", value : data[i].y1964},
            {year : "1965", value : data[i].y1965},
            {year : "1966", value : data[i].y1966},
            {year : "1967", value : data[i].y1967},
            {year : "1968", value : data[i].y1968},
            {year : "1969", value : data[i].y1969},
            {year : "1970", value : data[i].y1970},
            {year : "1971", value : data[i].y1971},
            {year : "1972", value : data[i].y1972},
            {year : "1973", value : data[i].y1973},
            {year : "1974", value : data[i].y1974},
            {year : "1975", value : data[i].y1975},
            {year : "1976", value : data[i].y1976},
            {year : "1977", value : data[i].y1977},
            {year : "1978", value : data[i].y1978},
            {year : "1979", value : data[i].y1979},
            {year : "1980", value : data[i].y1980},
            {year : "1981", value : data[i].y1981},
            {year : "1982", value : data[i].y1982},
            {year : "1983", value : data[i].y1983},
            {year : "1984", value : data[i].y1984},
            {year : "1985", value : data[i].y1985},
            {year : "1986", value : data[i].y1986},
            {year : "1987", value : data[i].y1987},
            {year : "1988", value : data[i].y1988},
            {year : "1989", value : data[i].y1989},
            {year : "1990", value : data[i].y1990},
            {year : "1991", value : data[i].y1991},
            {year : "1992", value : data[i].y1992},
            {year : "1993", value : data[i].y1993},
            {year : "1994", value : data[i].y1994},
            {year : "1995", value : data[i].y1995},
            {year : "1996", value : data[i].y1996},
            {year : "1997", value : data[i].y1997},
            {year : "1998", value : data[i].y1998},
            {year : "1999", value : data[i].y1999},
            {year : "2000", value : data[i].y2000},
            {year : "2001", value : data[i].y2001},
            {year : "2002", value : data[i].y2002},
            {year : "2003", value : data[i].y2003},
            {year : "2004", value : data[i].y2004},
            {year : "2005", value : data[i].y2005},
            {year : "2006", value : data[i].y2006},
            {year : "2007", value : data[i].y2007},
            {year : "2008", value : data[i].y2008},
            {year : "2009", value : data[i].y2009},
            {year : "2010", value : data[i].y2010},
            {year : "2011", value : data[i].y2011},
            {year : "2012", value : data[i].y2012},
            {year : "2013", value : data[i].y2013},
            {year : "2014", value : data[i].y2014}
        ]
    }
    countriesArr[i] = countriesObj[i];
}

console.log(countriesArr[0]);

function getCountryName(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < countriesArr.length; i++) {
        if (countriesArr[i].countryCode === id) {
            return countriesArr[i].countryName;
        }
    }
}

function getHowManyCountries() {
    return countriesArr.length;
}

d3.select(".howMany").text(getHowManyCountries);

function chooseCountry(d) {
    var countryId = d.id;
    console.log(countryId);
    for (var i = 0; i < countriesArr.length; i++) {
        if (countriesArr[i].countryCode === countryId) {

            if (countriesArr[i].years.value === undefined) {
                console.log("no data");
            }

            console.log(countriesArr[i].countryName);

            var min = d3.min(d3.extent(countriesArr[i].years, function(d) {return d.value;}));
            var max = d3.max(d3.extent(countriesArr[i].years, function(d) {return d.value}));
            yScale.domain([min, max]);

            var minYear = d3.min(countriesArr[i].years, function(d) {return d.year;});
            var maxYear = d3.max(countriesArr[i].years, function(d) {return d.year});
            xScale.domain([minYear, maxYear]);

            svgLineChart.selectAll("*")
                .remove();

            svgLineChart.selectAll(".line")
                .transition()
                .duration(300)
                .delay(20)
                .attr("d", line);

            svgLineChart.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (heightChart - margin.bottom) + ")")
                .attr("class","x axis")
                .call(xAxis);

            svgLineChart.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)")
                .attr("class","y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".5em")
                .attr("x",0 - (heightChart / 2))
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("POPULATION DENSITY"); 

            svgLineChart.append("path")
                .datum(countriesArr[i].years)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line);


            d3.select("#description")
                .text(countriesArr[i].countryName);
            }
        }
    return countryId;      
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "countries")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(countries, countries.objects.countries).features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
      var value = d.properties.size;
      if (value) {
          return color(value);
      }
      else {
          return "#747e87";
      }
  })
  .style("stroke", "#363b3f")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
  .attr("d", path)
  .on("click", function(d) {
      chooseCountry(d);
      d3.select(".selected").classed("selected", false);
      d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(50)
          .attr("fill", "#b0bf91");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      tooltip.classed('hidden', true);
      d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(50)
          .attr("fill", "#747e87")
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map(function(d) {
          return parseInt(d);
      });
      tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
          .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0] + 200) +
                  'px; top:' + (mouse[1] + 120) + 'px')
          .html(getCountryName(d.id));
  });

};
```

Please help because I really don't see the error here.

Comment: Can you create a plunk?

Comment: Why put your code without showing your data ?

Comment: sorry. The data is here: http://www.filedropper.com/countriesmodified

Comment: The CSV is in chinese?

Comment: no, why? it's normal file.... maybe you should try to open it in wordpad?